# How to interpret Cumulative Frequency from Stem Leaf Diagram?

Tags: statistics

Given stem-leaf diagram such as the following table:

Cumulative-Frequency Stem | Leaf

---

```
    v1            1   | 5 5 7
    v2            2   | 3 1 9
```

How to calculate $v_1$ and $v_2$?

What I am confused about is that the frequency is an attribute of a point, not a set of points so what does it mean to associate a single cumulative frequency to a set of points such as {15, 15, 17}?

Answer (score 0):

The six observations are 15, 15, 17, 21, 23, 29.
There are three in each group. I am not familiar
with this particular notation, but I would guess
that the line-by-line cumulative frequencies here are $v_1 = 3$ and
$v_2 = 6.$

You should compare this exercise with
any similar examples in your notes or text.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Unfortunately, I have no reference text for this, I just saw the question and I found that it did not make sense to me because it is valid to say that the value 15 has a frequency of 2, however the set {15,15,7} occurs 1 time and the stem leaf diagram leads to unique rows, so that the column will never have a value other than 1. How did you come up with the value v2=6 for instance please? Thanks again.

Comment: It seems we're both guessing then. // I think the key word here is 'cumulative."
In the first row we accumulate three counts and by the end of the second row we accumulate six. // The closest thing I've seen to this is that Minitab stemplots have some cumulative frequencies, and I'm trying to imitate that to the extent it applies here.

Comment: OK, I see your point, I guess now it makes sense...I will research this more...My last statistics course was in 1983!